# Is an s Corp LLC best for starting a small business marketing agency?

Tags: small-business

I want to start my own marketing agency where I will be employing people from across the US and international like India for example. The work will be done at their own location and sent back to me for review before sending it off to the client. Based on this information, which business entity should I create? LLC? S Corp? Or another?

Are there pros and cons to each type?